# What type can i set to the first param of setState in typescript? how can I pass dynamiclly state object to setState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I was intended to pass newState object to setState and in some condition I want add some more properties to newState but I got some type error here :
I tried to declare new State to `Pick<ItemListState, keyof ItemListState>`
but get type error

> TS2741: Property 'name' is missing in type '{ age: number; }' but required in type 'Pick

I also tried to declare new State to `{[key in keyof ItemListState]?: ItemListState[key]}`
but also get type error

```js
interface ItemListState {
    age: number;
    name: string;
}
class ItemList extends React.Component<{  }, ItemListState> {
    constructor (props: Readonly<{}>) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            age:1,
            name:'john',
        };
    }
    someHandler=(setName: boolean) => {
        /**
         * Error on newState  
         *  Error:(20, 15) TS2741: Property 'name' is missing in type '{ age: number; }' but required in type 'Pick<ItemListState, "age" | "name">'.
         */
        const newState: Pick<ItemListState, keyof ItemListState> = { age:2 };
        /**
         * Error on this.setState(newState):
         * 
         * Error:(26, 23) TS2345: Argument of type '{ age?: number | undefined; name?: string | undefined; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ItemListState | Pick<ItemListState, "name" | "age"> | ((prevState: Readonly<ItemListState>, props: Readonly<ItemListProps>) => ItemListState | ... 1 more ... | null) | null'.
         Type '{ age?: number | undefined; name?: string | undefined; }' is not assignable to type 'Pick<ItemListState, "name" | "age">'.
         Types of property 'name' are incompatible.
         Type 'string | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
         Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
         */
        const newState: {[key in keyof ItemListState]?: ItemListState[key]} = { age:2 };

        if (setName) {
            newState.name = 'snow';
        }
        this.setState(newState);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first error, `Error:(20, 15)` derives from `Pick<ItemListState, keyof ItemListState>` becoming `Pick<ItemListState, 'age' | 'name' >`. Essentially it's no different than passing `ItemListState`. If you wish to only propagate `age` then you want to `Pick<ItemListState, 'age'>` which would compile with `{age: 2}`

Your second error is for similar reason. `setState` expects the new state to be of type `ItemListState` but you're passing something this type:

```
const newState: {
  age?: number | undefined;
  name?: string | undefined;
};
```

Which is not compatible. It's not the most beautiful solution, but without additional context I think this is fair:

```
class ItemList extends React.Component<{}, ItemListState> {
  constructor(props: Readonly<{}>) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      age: 1,
      name: 'john',
    };
  }
  someHandler = (setName: boolean) => {
    let newState: ItemListState = { ...this.state, age: 2 };

    if (setName) {
      newState.name = 'snow';
    }

    this.setState(newState);
  };
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. but i still want to pass partial states to setState not all of them  Is that impossible?

Comment: It's possible but `Pick<>` is a bit troublesome to work with. Would this fulfill your needs: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQFDAB2MWUBeWcAkkyADLCowAyjGRM4AbxpxpKAOZYAXHHoBXEACNmAbikz6yEIrgCoDWToC+NGrgA2adFyy9+8LAA8m9ACbpseGAA6AGESSHosRgAecQsAGk5uPgFhUSwAPgldXAh6ExV8aAAKMGIwVCV-b1zbAE8Yi3SASiyZYxUwZhKy1CadNpgAC35AgTS4AF5WtrkjAEY43Tb9QyUyACsIQfoyRbaLfrgraVQSLAAJZB9bZkm4ItQsGAA5AyN1CAgbq5aJzMk2jd4BEAO6pJg6JZwYAEe6PF5vFoAmag8HsKbiZDyBQAJgSK0UZFQ9AgILIxxkFjgWFsj2myywYJEYgxWMUOIp0isUKGI3haKKqOZWD6ugONAsQA